# why is my image not displayed with <p:graphicImage/>?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I think I tried everything I found in the other answers.

I am using liferay and spring-boot microservices. I am taking an image by calling an endpoint from microservice and try to display it with liferay. But it doesn't show up.

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"

 <p:panelGrid style="vertical-align: top; width:100%;" id="applicant-panel">
        <p:row>
            <p:column rowspan="5" colspan="2" styleClass="f2">

                <p:graphicImage value="#{somebean.image}" width="200"
                                id="that-image">
                </p:graphicImage>

            </p:column>

        </p:row>
 </p:panelGrid>
</ui:composition>
```

In somebean:

```
   public StreamedContent getImage()  {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

        if (context.getCurrentPhaseId() == PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE) {
            return new DefaultStreamedContent();
        }
        else {        
            return new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(SomeUtils.getThatImage(selectedPers.getid()))); //it has data in, it is not null
        }
    }
```

I really don't know why it is not displayed. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @JasperdeVries I think it should be enough to reproduce the example...

Comment: No, it is not. Please read https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/12_0_0/#/components/graphicimage and https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/12_0_0/#/core/dynamiccontent?id=iterating-component-support

Answer (score -3):

I solved this by setting the steam attribute to false. I don't know why this worked, as I am returning a stream...

```
 <p:graphicImage value="#{somebean.image}" stream="false" width="200"
                                id="some-image">
 </p:graphicImage>
```

Comment: Thats not really a good solution, it will be rendered as base64 now.

Comment: Indeed that sounds as a workaround.